# How to access webcam with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to access the webcam in JS for use with opencv.js however the recommended code for accessing the webcam does not work and instead returns a null object - the important code is as follows:

```
  <video autoplay="true" id="videoElement">
  <script>
    function initialize_camera(){
      // initializing the user webcam
      let video = document.getElementById("#videoInput"); // video is the id of video tag
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
          .then(function(stream) {
              video.srcObject = stream;
              video.play();
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
              console.log("An error occurred! " + err);
          });
    }
    initialize_camera();
</script>
```

When running in the chrome browser I receive the error:
"An error occurred! TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'srcObject')" for line 19.

How can I access the webcam using Javascript?

Comment: Your element id is different in the HTML and the JS.

Comment: That seems to have worked, thank you! I am beginner to JavaScript as you can probably tell!

Comment: It is important to read and understand the error message to improve your coding and debugging skills. In this case the error is saying that cannot set a property (srcObject) in to a null object. From that error you can tell that the video variable is null, thus the error must be related with the initialization of that variable. In this case as you have already noticed it was a typo between the HTML and JS ids.